# Convert javascript object to number

Tags: javascript

I have an object:

```
[{"Spalte":3}]
```

How can I get only 3 ?

I tried something like that:

```
    var s = JSON.stringify(data);  // [{"Spalte":3}] as String
    var d = parseInt(s); // typeof d = number,
```

When I tried to alert(d) I receive NaN.

Comment: `data[0].Spalte`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably meant to do

```
var d = JSON.parse(s)[0].Spalte;
```

`s` contains a serialization of an object as JSON. So we parse it with `JSON.parse` to get back the original object and then use standard javascript to extract the numeric field. Notice there is no need for `parseInt`.

Alternatively, you can stringify the numeric field by itself:

```
var data = [{"Spalte":3}];
var s = JSON.stringify(data[0].Spalte);
var d = JSON.parse(s);
```

or even:

```
var data = [{"Spalte":3}];
var s = data[0].Spalte + ""; // simply convert a number to string
var d = parseInt(s); // parse the string back to a number.
```

Comment: There is absolutely no need to use any JSON.* methods or string parsing. As Maxx already commented, a very simple `data[0].Spalte` does the trick. Also, you probably meant `JSON.parse(s)` instead of `JSON.parse('3')`?

Comment: Question is about stingify data and parsing a number out of it, not about what others believe about others having mistakes in the question. The mistake is the beliefe that the parseInt parse the int out from a string. To believe JSON.stringify is JSON.parse is unbelieveblabb.

Answer (score 2):

```
var data = [{
  "Spalte": 3,
  valueOf() {
    return Spalte;
  }
}];

console.log(+data[0]) // 3
```

https://javascript.info/object-toprimitive

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [{"Spalte":3}]
var s = JSON.stringify(data);  // [{"Spalte":3}] as String
var d = s.replace(/[^0-9]*/g, ''); // typeof d == number

//replace all non-digits with nothing
console.log(d)
```